# activates an activty from one of a java class

Tags: android

Is it possible to start an `Activity` using an `Intent` from a class that extends `LinearLayout`?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (inputConnection == null) 
        return;

    if (v.getId()==R.id.replay) {
        //do not work ???
        Intent intent= new Intent(this.MyKeyboard,Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    if (v.getId() == R.id.button_delete) {
        CharSequence selectedText = inputConnection.getSelectedText(0);
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedText)) {
            inputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
        } else {
            inputConnection.commitText("", 1);
        }
    } else {
        String value = keyValues.get(v.getId());
        inputConnection.commitText(value, 1);
    }
}

public void setInputConnection(InputConnection ic) {
    this.inputConnection = ic;
}
```

Comment: What is `this.MyKeyboard` ? Is it a Context as described in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) ?

Comment: it's the class name

Comment: Is this code inside an Activity ?

Comment: in a java class that extends LinearLayout

Comment: Use the context of the View or from your LinearLayout to start the activity and add the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to your intent. Usually I think the better approach is to have the click listener inside of your activity, that is displaying the layout and to start the intent there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that `this.MyKeyboard`is not a [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) object, since it is a subclass of LinearLayout. Hopefully, this class extends the View class so you can access your context using [getContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()). Your code should look like :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Edit:

If your context is not an Activity context you need to add the flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) using [addFlags()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#addFlags(int)) :

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: You need to add FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, if the intent is not started from an activity context. Otherwise, this is correct. (btw. LinearLayout extends ViewGroup, which extends View)

Answer (score 0):

`LinearLayout` extends `ViewGroup`, which extends `View`, so you may access your context using [`getContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext())

```
Intent intent= new Intent(this.getContext(),Main2Activity.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```